# How to copy (yank) from file 1 and paste (put) in file 2 in vi using buffer?

Tags: linux, unix, vi

I want to know the process for copying data from file 1 and paste the data into file 2 in vi editor using a buffer.

Can you please tell me the step by step process.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `vi` manual:

> **6.5.6.3 Using Named Buffers**
>
> To repeatedly insert a group of lines in various places within a document, you can yank (or delete) the lines
> into a named buffer. You specify named buffers by preceding a command
> with double quotes (") and a name for the buffer. For example, to yank
> four lines into the named buffer a, type "a4yy. You can use several
> different buffers. For example, you might also delete text from one
> location and add it to several others. To delete 12 lines into the
> named buffer b, type "b12dd.
>
> To insert the text, precede the p or P command with n, where n is the
> named buffer. For example, to insert the lines saved in buffer b, type
> "bP.
>
> You can overwrite named buffers with new lines. The buffers are saved
> until you exit vi.
>
> When you use named buffers, you can safely delete and yank other text
> without affecting the lines you have already saved in the named
> buffers -- unless, of course, you purposely overwrite the named
> buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't *really* need the buffer contents...

then you can also just directly do something like this to *overwrite* **file2**:

```
:4,12w file2
```

or *append* to it with something like:

```
:5,20w >> file2
```

Of course other standard `ex` line addressing options are also available.